# Connect to DB2 database in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Could you please let me know how to connect DB2 database and execute stored procedures in JMeter?

I am trying to connect via JDBC, but I am not able to debug where the error is.

Is there any plugin available to accomplish stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

And this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request

> Parameter types   Column

To debug look at jmeter.log